# Wrong argument kind when using GHC Generics

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, typeclass

I've been following the [GHC.Generics](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC.Generics) tutorial to make a simple generic typeclass for providing default values for arbitrary types. However when I try to load my file (relevant snippet, which still produces the error)

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures, DeriveGeneric, TypeOperators, FlexibleContexts #-}
import GHC.Generics

class Default a where
    def :: a
    default def :: (Generic a, GDefault (Rep a)) => a
    def = to gdef

class GDefault f where
    gdef :: f a

instance (Default a, Default b) => GDefault (a :+: b) where
    gdef (L1 x) = gdef x
    gdef (R1 x) = gdef x
```

I get the following error:

```
Generic.hs:12:46:
    The first argument of ‘:+:’ should have kind ‘* -> *’,
      but ‘a’ has kind ‘*’
    In the instance declaration for ‘GDefault (a :+: b)’
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're doing here, but is it just a case of a missing kind signature? It looks like GHC is defaulting the kind of `a` to `*`. Try `(a :: * -> *)` with `-XKindSignatures`.

Comment: Thanks. But that just changes the error to `The signature specified kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘a’ has kind ‘*’`

Comment: Okay, it looks like what you're trying to do just won't work. In the class `Default`, the parameter `a` *must* have kind `*` because `def` returns a value of type `a`. In your instance for `GDefault`, `(:+:)` expects its first paratmeter to have kind `*->*`, but you have the constraint `Default a`, which means `a` has kind `*`.

Comment: @eric So how would you fix that? I'm still learning Generics so it's quite possible my code is silly.

Comment: The problem is certianly not specific to Generics; your code simply has a vanilly kind mismatch. I don't know much about Generics, and I don't know what you are trying to do, so it will be hard to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't you mean...?

```
instance (GDefault a, GDefault b) => GDefault (a :+: b) where ...
  --      ^           ^
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was something silly, my code still has errors after the fix, but at least _this_ question is fixed.